# how to return a private char array[][] from class to func in c++

Tags: c++

I want to return a private char[][] array from class to another class
How can i do it ?

```
class board {
private:


char boardGame[SIZEROW][SIZECOL];

public:

char** getBoard(){

return boardGame;}
```

Comment: You can't return a copy of arrays but you can return a reference (or pointer) to it. Example: `char (&getBoard())[SIZEROW][SIZECOL] { return boardGame; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can only return a **pointer** or a **reference** to an array through a function. Both of these are shown below:

**Method 1:** Return pointer to array

```
class board {
    private:
    
        char boardGame[8][6];
    
    public:
    
        //getBoard is a function that returns a pointer to 2D array 
        char (*getBoard())[8][6]
        {
            return &boardGame;
        }
};
```

**Method 2:** Return reference to array

```
class board {
    private:
    
        char boardGame[8][6];
    
    public:
    
        //getBoard is a function that returns a reference to 2D array 
        char (&getBoard())[8][6]
        {
            return boardGame;
        }
};
```